# Looping over an array but skipping some of the index

Tags: python

I have the following loop which works when creating an output file. There are n-number of rows and 24 columns and it's going each row and column to create plots. `variable` below is from index [3:24]. Now the `variable` is created somewhere in before this loop in the code that I don't want to touch. I want to be able to overwrite the `variable` and not go over some of the indexes from [3:24] such as index 22, 20, 3. How can I implement that below? I tried creating another if statement so that when it reaches index 20 it would break. Anyways my solution doesn't work so I was hoping to get an answer here. Thanks!

```
for row in range(len(self.CSVResult)):
    if (abs(self.CSVResult[row][variable-1]) < 1.2E20):
       skipsw = 1
       break
```

For example, `variable` is looping from index 3 to 24, once it reaches index 22 it will skip and continue to 21. Then once it reaches index 20 it will skip and reach 19. Until it reach index 3 again and then skip that value too.

Comment: Could you specify how you want to choose the indices? You mention index 22, 20, 3, but it's not quite clear to me what the issue is here. Could you make a minimal reproducible example, where the 'error' you are getting is easier to understand?

Comment: @SteinnHauserMagnusson

For example, `variable` is looping from index 3 to 24, once it reaches index 22 it will skip and continue to 21. Then once it reaches 20 index it will skip and reach 19. Until it reach index 3 again and then skip that value too.

Comment: Could you "pop" the items out or you don't want to erase them? Besides, if the number of items you want to skip is known, a condition like `if row.value in [3, 20, 22]: continue`  could work?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish here. You want to skip reading certain columns from the CSV file? Or you want to skip certain rows based on the values of those rows in a given column? Or find the index of a row where some condition is met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this help?

```py
skip_values = [22, 21, 3]
for row in range(len(self.CSVResult)):
    if variable in skip_values:
        continue
    elif (abs(self.CSVResult[row][variable-1]) < 1.2E20):
        skipsw = 1
        break
```

If I understood correctly, you want to define some 'skip values', where if variable is equal one of those, then it does not do the rest of the code.

Comment: I get `elif` =>  invalid syntax

Comment: Are you sure your indentation is correct? You can also simply try to write `if` again instead of `elif` since the `continue` statement skips it anyway